# C: Address trap error when accessing a struct with odd no. of members

Tags: struct, pad, packed, xc16

I am working with MPLABX with compiler xc16-gcc developing for the 16-bit dsPIC33CH128MP508 microcontroller. I am making code to read from RTC through I2C.
I have defined the following structs:

```
typedef struct tagRTC_VL_SECONDSBITS{
    uint8_t SECONDS: 7 ;
    uint8_t VL:1 ;      /* 0: clock integrity is guarantee */ 
}sRTC_VL_SECONDSBITS_t;

typedef struct tagRTC_MINUTESBITS{
    uint8_t MINUTES: 7 ;
    uint8_t :1 ;
}sRTC_MINUTESBITS_t;

typedef struct tagRTC_HOURSBITS{
    uint8_t HOURS: 6 ;
    uint8_t :2 ;
}sRTC_HOURSBITS_t;

typedef struct tagRTC_DAYSBITS{
    uint8_t DAYS: 6 ;
    uint8_t :2 ;
}sRTC_DAYSBITS_t;

typedef struct tagRTC_WEEKDAYSBITS{
    uint8_t WEEKDAYS: 3 ;
    uint8_t :5 ;
}sRTC_WEEKDAYSBITS_t;

typedef struct tagRTC_CENTURY_MONTHSBITS{
    uint8_t MONTHS: 5 ;
    uint8_t :2 ;
    uint8_t C:1 ;
}sRTC_CENTURY_MONTHSBITS_t;

typedef struct tagRTC_YEARSBITS{
    uint8_t YEARS ;
}sRTC_YEARSBITS_t;

typedef struct tagRTC_TIME{
    sRTC_VL_SECONDSBITS_t sec;
    sRTC_MINUTESBITS_t min ;
    sRTC_HOURSBITS_t hr ;
    sRTC_DAYSBITS_t day ;
    sRTC_WEEKDAYSBITS_t wDay ;
    sRTC_CENTURY_MONTHSBITS_t month ;
    sRTC_YEARSBITS_t year ;

}sRTC_TIME_t ;
```

The issue with struct `sRTC_TIME_t` has odd numbers of members, the memory alignment is packed automatically by the compiler. The reading from RTC requires the struct packed also.

When trying to read the first member `sec`  the code trap with `TRAPS_ADDRESS_ERR = 2, /** Address error Trap vector */`.

`sRTC_TIME_t time;`

`second_reading  = time.sec.SECONDS;`

When we add an eighth dummy member in the struct `sRTC_TIME_t` there is no error!

What could be the source of this issue?